# How to Run a Cron Job when the code is in Other File - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, node-cron

I am trying to execute a cron every 1 hour.

For which I have initiated the cron job in my `index.js` file as below

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const readDocuments = require("./cronJobs/readDocuments");
var task = cron.schedule('0 0 */1 * * *', readDocuments);

task.start();
```

Where as the actual code to be executed has been written in `./cronJobs/readDocuments` and the code inside this file is below, where I am trying to read a csv file.

***readDocuments.js***

```
const ResponseManager = require("../common/ResponseManager");

var fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
console.log('Read Document....')
try {

var filepath = "../files/abc.csv";
fs.createReadStream(filepath)
.on('error', () => {
// handle error
})
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (row) => {
console.log('rowrowrow',row)
})
.on('end', () => {
// handle end of CSV
})
} catch (error) {
console.log('errorerror',error)
res.status(500).json(ResponseManager(false, error.message));
}
```

When I run the node js in cmd with `node index.js`, the console `Read Document....` is getting displayed but the other code is not getting executed.
It is giving me  `throw 'execution must be a function';` error

How do I resolve this or what is the actual procedure to execute the code inside a file with cron job from index.js.

Please help. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `cron.schedule()` must be function. You need to wrap the code into a function and export it from the module.

```js
const ResponseManager = require("../common/ResponseManager");
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('csv-parser');

module.exports = function () {
  console.log('Read Document....')
  try {
    const filepath = "../files/abc.csv";
    fs.createReadStream(filepath)
      .on('error', () => {
        // handle error
      })
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (row) => {
        console.log('rowrowrow', row)
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        // handle end of CSV
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('errorerror', error)
    res.status(500).json(ResponseManager(false, error.message));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to export the cron function and consume it on your file